# "Initializing…. Please wait" error on installing android app created via phonegap build

Tags: phonegap-build

Created a basic HTML, CSS, Javascript app using phonegap desktop developer app, phonegap mobile developer app, uploaded this to github public repo.
After creating a phonegap-build account , I created the android apk build using phonegap-build referring the source from github public repo url.
Installation of apk file in android device went fine, but when I try to open the app, it is stuck at this error "Initializing…. Please wait". This is stuck at this stage for long time and can't get past it.

Answer (score 0):

Found that , I had enabled 'hydration' while creating the apk using phonegap-build.
After disabling the hydration, and doing a rebuild and re-generated the apk, installed it on the device, now it is good.